# Exception: java.awt.HeadlessException thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "main"

Tags: java, google-colaboratory, headless

I am trying to use a program called flexible meccano in colab but when I try to run the .sh I get this issue.

```
! ./flexiblemeccano-linux.sh

Configuring the installer...
Searching for JVM on the system...
Extracting installation data...
Running the installer wizard...

Exception: java.awt.HeadlessException thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "main"
```

The .sh file needed JDK 6 before so I used this code to install it and then I got the exception shown above.

```
import os       #importing os to set environment variable
def install_java():
  !apt-get install -y openjdk-8-jdk-headless -qq > /dev/null      #install openjdk
  os.environ["JAVA_HOME"] = "/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64"     #set environment variable
  !java -version       #check java version
install_java()
```

Is it possible to fix this?

Comment: You installed a "headless" JRE + JDK (i. e. a JRE for running on non-graphical systems) and are trying to run a graphical piece of software on it. It might work if you install a regular, non-headless JRE + JDK. Emphasis on "might".

Comment: Thank you for the input. I removed headless from the install but now I get this issue "No X11 DISPLAY variable was set, but this program performed an operation which requires it." I think  the issue may be as you mentioned,  that I'm trying to run a graphical piece of software on it. Is there any way to do this in Colab?

Comment: Yes, X11 is responsible for all kinds of display things and this message indicates no X11 is actually running and available. You could possibly run a X server (Xvfb, possibly) in your user space, but it'll take some fiddling and Linux knowledge. So, uh... why? What is even the point? Whatever you are doing, there has to be a more fitting tool for it.

Comment: Well I'm trying to use this software called Flexiblemeccano but it's linux based and I don't have my Windows computer set up for that. I thought Colab would be easier to set it up.

Comment: Use VirtualBox or similar - installing Ubuntu in it should take no more than half an hour.